# MYSQL Error:1054 - Unknown Column

Tags: mysql

just having some trouble with an SQL update in PHP. Listed below is an extract of the function:

```
    $captain = $this->getUserName();
    $member = $textParts[1];
    $memberNo = 'member1';

    $sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE ajax_chat_draft_teams SET '.$memberNo.'='.$member.' WHERE captain='.$captain.'';

    $result = $this->db->sqlQuery($sqlUpdate);
```

When the Query is reached it throws the following error:

```
Query: UPDATE ajax_chat_draft_teams SET member1=user WHERE captain=Oolius
Error-Report: Unknown column 'Oolius' in 'where clause'
Error-Code: 1054 error occured!
```

The table ajax_chat_draft_teams has 5 fields: captain, member1, member2, member3, member4
(Note: There is a record in the table where the captain is Oolius and all members are NULL).

I'm failing to see what is wrong with my SQL statement. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Toss quotes around Oolius, it's bothering me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE ajax_chat_draft_teams SET '.$memberNo.' = "'.$member.'" WHERE captain = "'.$captain.'"';
```

Comment: Thanks heaps worked a charm. That was causing me way to much strife.

Answer (score 1):

String literals need to be surrounded in single quotes. The query should look like this:

`UPDATE ajax_chat_draft_teams SET member1='user' WHERE captain = 'Oolius'`

Also, consider using [PDO](http://us.php.net/pdo) and bind variables.

Comment: +1 for binding, SQL like this is begging for an injection attack

Answer (score 0):

You need to put Oolius in quotes other MySQL thinks it is a column name.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

> $sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE ajax_chat_draft_teams SET
>   '.$memberNo.'="'.$member.'" WHERE captain="'.$captain.'"';

i hope it will help you.